# ontouchlistener code cant be applied on int

Tags: android, this, ontouchlistener

i build an android application on android studio, and i put if statement on the command ontouchlistener code, and show message problem on "this", i think because it need int not intent ?! so i need to solve it please :)

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    logpassj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logpass);
    logpassjH = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logpassH);
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
logpassj.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                logpassjH.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
            if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                logpassj.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if(mPasswordView.getText().toString().equals("123456789"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ITCutiesReaderAppActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                            .setTicker("Calcupital")
                            .setContentTitle("Calcupital")
                            .setContentText("User Information has been updated successfully")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher4)
                            .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
                    noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
                    mPasswordView.setText("");



                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Invalid ID Information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPasswordView.setText("");

                }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: its not clear exactly what issue you are having.  If the issue you are having is with "this" it is because "this" refers to the instance of OnTouchListener, not your activity/fragment.  If in a fragment use getActivity() instead of "this".

Comment: this is my activity :
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

Comment: see the image:
http://s7.postimg.org/vss395v8r/code.jpg
this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refeer the **"outer this"** as a valid `Context` object from the `OnTouchListener` methods, because inside an object of type `OnTouchListener` *this* is of type `OnTouchListener`.

Change your code to this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    logpassj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logpass);
    logpassjH = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logpassH);
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
logpassj.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                logpassjH.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
            if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                logpassj.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if(mPasswordView.getText().toString().equals("123456789"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ITCutiesReaderAppActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setTicker("Calcupital")
                            .setContentTitle("Calcupital")
                            .setContentText("User Information has been updated successfully")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher4)
                            .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
                    noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
                    mPasswordView.setText("");



                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Invalid ID Information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mPasswordView.setText("");

                }

            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
this
```

to

```
MainActivity.this
```

Here,
 MainActivity -> Your Activity Name

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that 'this' refers to the OnTouchListener not the activity.

You need to move the contents of that if statement to a private function

```
if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        { myFunction();   ...

private void myFunction(){
   // create your intent here
   // 'this' will now refer to the activity
```